# Change maxbibnames mid document

Tags: biblatex

I use biblatex to show references list in multiple places in my document (using `\newrefsection` and `\printbibliography`). At the moment I use

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxbibnames=99}
```

in the preamble to show all authors my biblio. However, for some reference lists within the document, I want to show only a limited number of authors. I tried doing

```
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxbibnames=3}
```

inside the document, but got `LaTeX Error: Can be used only in preamble.`

Is there a way to change the `maxbibname` mid document? Or another way to achieve display a varying number of authors?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxbibnames=99}

\begin{document}
\newrefsection
\nocite{sigfridsson,aksin,worman,geer,pines}
\printbibliography

% Change authors
% \ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxbibnames=1}

\newrefsection
\nocite{sigfridsson,aksin,worman,geer,pines}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a chance you could share a short example document with us that shows what exactly you are doing? `maxbibnames` is just implemented via an internal counter and it would be possible to manipulate on the fly, but some entry data may (in)directly depend on `maxbibnames` via data generated by Biber (label and uniqueness data) in which case the output could be weird in edge cases if we change `maxbibnames` on the fly to a value different than we passed to Biber.

Comment: Added a minimum working example.

Comment: Do you want to use a `numeric` style as in your example in your real-world document as well? In that case the uniqueness considerations I mentioned above are not an issue?

Comment: Ah, sorry for not clarifying. yes, I want to use `numeric` style.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `biblatex` side `(min|max)(bib|cite)names` is just implemented via a simple counter that could in theory be redefined anywhere in your document.

But since `biblatex` also passes `(min|max)(bib|cite)names` on to the backend Biber or BibTeX to use for sorting purposes and for uniqueness and label calculation, you may end up with undesirable results in edge cases when you change the value of `(min|max)(bib|cite)names` on the fly in your document.

In your case of the `numeric` style there is no such danger, so we can just set the counter wherever we want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{maxbibnames=99}

\makeatletter
\newrobustcmd*{\SetMinBibnames}[1]{\numdef\blx@minbibnames{#1}}
\newrobustcmd*{\SetMaxBibnames}[1]{\numdef\blx@maxbibnames{#1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\newrefsection
\nocite{sigfridsson,aksin,geer}
\printbibliography

\newrefsection
\SetMaxBibnames{1}
\nocite{sigfridsson,aksin,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: "Özge Aksın, Hayati Türkmen, Levent Artok, Bekir C¸etinkaya, Chaoying Ni, Orhan Büyükgüngör, and Erhan Özkal." vs "Özge Aksın et al."]